Run a loop inside a nested array in swift
I am trying to get result by using a for loop inside nested response by not getting the required result.
I have tried but not getting the desired response.
Required result is as below.

[
 [["P-1 Test one","P-1 Test Two","P-1 Test Three"]],
 [["P-2 Test One"","P-2 Test One"],["P-2 A-1 Test one","P-2 A-1 Test two","P-2 A-1 Test three","P-2 A-1 Test four"],["P-2 A-2 Test one","P-2 A-2 Test two","P-2 A-3 Test three","P-2 A-4 Test four"]],
 [["P-3 Test One"],["P-3 A-1 Test one","P-3 A-1 Test Two","P-3 A-1 Test three","P-3 A-1 Test four"]]
 ]


I am using below json response to get the required result.
{
    "page_size": 20,
    "page": 1,
    "count": 209,
    "results": [
        {
            "_score": null,
            "plink_id": "plifnW",
        "customer_name": "Primary member one",
            "packages": [
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-1 Test one",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "Test-one-slug"
                },
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-1 Test Two",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "Test-Two-slug"
                },
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-1 Test Three",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                    "package_price": 160,
                    "offer_price": 99
                },
                    "slug_name": "Test-Two-slug"
                }
            ],
            "verification_remark": "Duplicate Booking",
            "additional_members": []
        },
        {
            "_score": null,
            "plink_id": "plifnW",
         "customer_name": "Primary member two",
            "packages": [
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-2 Test One",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "Test one slug"
                },
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-2 Test One",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                    "package_price": 160,
                    "offer_price": 99
                },
                    "slug_name": "Test one slug"
                }
            ],
            "verification_remark": "Duplicate Booking",
            "additional_members": [
                {
                    "plink_id": null,
                    "alloted_time": null,
                    "customer_name": "Additional member one",
                    "packages": [
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-1 Test one",
                            "slug_name": "Test_one_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-1 Test two",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Two_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-1 Test three",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Three_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-1 Test four",
                            "slug_name": "Test_four_slug"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "plink_id": null,
                    "alloted_time": null,
                    "customer_name": "Additional member Two",
                    "packages": [
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-2 Test one",
                            "slug_name": "Test_one_slug"
                        },
                    {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-2 Test two",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Two_slug"
                    },
                    {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-3 Test three",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Three_slug"
                    },
                    {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-4 Test four",
                            "slug_name": "Test_four_slug"
                        }
                    ]
                }
                ]
        },
          {
            "_score": null,
            "plink_id": "plifnW",
         "customer_name": "Primary member Three",
            "packages": [
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-3 Test One",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "test five slug"
                }
            ],
            "verification_remark": "Duplicate Booking",
            "additional_members": [
                {
                    "plink_id": null,
                    "alloted_time": null,
                    "customer_name": "P-3-A-1 additional member",
                    "packages": [
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-3 A-1 Test one",
                            "slug_name": "Test_one_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-3 A-1 Test Two",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Two_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-3 A-1 Test three",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Three_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-3 A-1 Test four",
                            "slug_name": "Test_four_slug"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


Here in this response the parameter "additional_mamber" can be empty or can have multiple member or tests.
I have used following code to get the result.
for testResult in self.bookingArray?.results ?? [] {
    var testPackageArrayOne = [[String]]()
    for testPackage in testResult.packages ?? [] {
        testPackageArrayOne.append([testPackage.name ?? ""])
    }
    for member in testResult.additional_members ?? [] {
        var newAdditionArray = [String]()
        for additionalMemberTests in member.packages ?? [] {
            newAdditionArray.append(additionalMemberTests.name ?? "")
        }
        testPackageArrayOne.append(newAdditionArray)
    }
    print("testPackageArrayOne==>>",testPackageArrayOne)
    arrayOfTests.append(testPackageArrayOne)
    print("arrayOfTestArrays==>>",arrayOfTests)
}
// Print the resulting array of arrays
for array in arrayOfTests {
    print("individual array for every member ==>>",array)
}
print("member and additional members array ==>>",self.memberNameArray)
                

But not getting the desired result.

Not sure why the OP is getting the downvotes and or his post getting votes to close. The question looks pretty clear to me regarding the OP expected results.

Not sure why would you need a third level on your array but should be pretty straight forward using functional programing (map, flatMap):
let data = Data("""
{
    "page_size": 20,
    "page": 1,
    "count": 209,
    "results": [
        {
            "_score": null,
            "plink_id": "plifnW",
            "customer_name": "Primary member one",
            "packages": [
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-1 Test one",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "Test-one-slug"
                },
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-1 Test Two",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "Test-Two-slug"
                },
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-1 Test Three",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "Test-Two-slug"
                }
            ],
            "verification_remark": "Duplicate Booking",
            "additional_members": []
        },
        {
            "_score": null,
            "plink_id": "plifnW",
            "customer_name": "Primary member two",
            "packages": [
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-2 Test One",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "Test one slug"
                },
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-2 Test One",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "Test one slug"
                }
            ],
            "verification_remark": "Duplicate Booking",
            "additional_members": [
                {
                    "plink_id": null,
                    "alloted_time": null,
                    "customer_name": "Additional member one",
                    "packages": [
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-1 Test one",
                            "slug_name": "Test_one_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-1 Test two",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Two_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-1 Test three",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Three_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-1 Test four",
                            "slug_name": "Test_four_slug"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "plink_id": null,
                    "alloted_time": null,
                    "customer_name": "Additional member Two",
                    "packages": [
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-2 Test one",
                            "slug_name": "Test_one_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-2 Test two",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Two_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-3 Test three",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Three_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-2 A-4 Test four",
                            "slug_name": "Test_four_slug"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_score": null,
            "plink_id": "plifnW",
            "customer_name": "Primary member Three",
            "packages": [
                {
                    "is_addon": false,
                    "addon_price": 0,
                    "parameter": 1,
                    "name": "P-3 Test One",
                    "id": 54,
                    "package_city_prices": {
                        "package_price": 160,
                        "offer_price": 99
                    },
                    "slug_name": "test five slug"
                }
            ],
            "verification_remark": "Duplicate Booking",
            "additional_members": [
                {
                    "plink_id": null,
                    "alloted_time": null,
                    "customer_name": "P-3-A-1 additional member",
                    "packages": [
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-3 A-1 Test one",
                            "slug_name": "Test_one_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-3 A-1 Test Two",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Two_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-3 A-1 Test three",
                            "slug_name": "Test_Three_slug"
                        },
                        {
                            "is_addon": false,
                            "tat_time": null,
                            "name": "P-3 A-1 Test four",
                            "slug_name": "Test_four_slug"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
""".utf8
)


// MARK: - Booking
struct Booking: Codable {
    let pageSize, page, count: Int
    let results: [Result]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pageSize = "page_size"
        case page, count, results
    }
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
//    let score: Int?
    let plinkID, customerName: String
    let packages: [ResultPackage]
    let verificationRemark: String
    let additionalMembers: [AdditionalMember]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//        case score = "_score"
        case plinkID = "plink_id"
        case customerName = "customer_name"
        case packages
        case verificationRemark = "verification_remark"
        case additionalMembers = "additional_members"
    }
}

// MARK: - AdditionalMember
struct AdditionalMember: Codable {
//    let plinkID: String?
//    let allotedTime: Date?
    let customerName: String
    let packages: [AdditionalMemberPackage]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//        case plinkID = "plink_id"
//        case allotedTime = "alloted_time"
        case customerName = "customer_name"
        case packages
    }
}

// MARK: - AdditionalMemberPackage
struct AdditionalMemberPackage: Codable {
    let isAddon: Bool
//    let tatTime: Date?
    let name, slugName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isAddon = "is_addon"
//        case tatTime = "tat_time"
        case name
        case slugName = "slug_name"
    }
}

// MARK: - ResultPackage
struct ResultPackage: Codable {
    let isAddon: Bool
    let addonPrice, parameter: Int
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    let packageCityPrices: PackageCityPrices
    let slugName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isAddon = "is_addon"
        case addonPrice = "addon_price"
        case parameter, name, id
        case packageCityPrices = "package_city_prices"
        case slugName = "slug_name"
    }
}

// MARK: - PackageCityPrices
struct PackageCityPrices: Codable {
    let packagePrice, offerPrice: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case packagePrice = "package_price"
        case offerPrice = "offer_price"
    }
}


let bookingArray = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Booking.self, from: data)
var results: [[[String]]] = []
for result in bookingArray?.results ?? [] {
    let packages = result.packages.map(\.name)
    let additionalMembers = result.additionalMembers.flatMap(\.packages).map(\.name)
    if additionalMembers.isEmpty {
        results.append([packages])
    } else {
        results.append([packages, additionalMembers])
    }
}


for res in results {
    print(res)
}


Should print:

[["P-1 Test one", "P-1 Test Two", "P-1 Test Three"]]
[["P-2 Test One", "P-2 Test One"], ["P-2 A-1 Test one", "P-2 A-1 Test two", "P-2 A-1 Test three", "P-2 A-1 Test four", "P-2 A-2 Test one", "P-2 A-2 Test two", "P-2 A-3 Test three", "P-2 A-4 Test four"]]
[["P-3 Test One"], ["P-3 A-1 Test one", "P-3 A-1 Test Two", "P-3 A-1 Test three", "P-3 A-1 Test four"]]


or even simpler
let results = bookingArray?.results.map { result in 
    let packages = result.packages.map(\.name)
    let additionalMembers = result.additionalMembers.flatMap(\.packages).map(\.name)
    return additionalMembers.isEmpty ? [packages] : [packages, additionalMembers]
} ?? []


Hi Leo,
Thanks for the answer, I tried using same but getting issue as below.
"Cannot infer key path type from context; consider explicitly specifying a root type"
and
"Value of type '[BookingListAdditionalMember]' has no member 'packages'"

Just check your model property correct name. I used the same shown in your example. Xcode should autocomplete it for you after the period

if i use,
let additionalMembers = result.additional_members.flatMap(.first?.packages).map(.first?.name)
its not showing error

If you edit your question and post your model declaration I can help you fix it properly.

Actually the model is very large data. But let me try to get only relevant data for the same.

@Abhishekkumar Check my last edit. You can change the model if needed.

Existing model is using object mapper.
And the previous developer who was working on that project had created function inside viewmodel and used same model within the callApi func.
So I am tring to do same.
but the edit that you provided has codable.

func getAllBookingListApiCall(){
params = ["page": pageCount];
viewModel.callGetApi(params: params) { status, data, errorMsg in
if self.pageCount == 1 {
self.bookingArray = data
let bookings: [BookingListResults]? = data.results
var activeOrderResults: [BookingListResults] = []
var pastOrderResults: [BookingListResults] = []
this is the func in which i am tring to get the result

Make yourself a favor and get rid of Object Mapper. Codable has been around for more than 5 years. Btw edit your post. Don't post code at the comments section.

Yes there is alot in that project that is need to be updated and change.
Thats why i'm looking for temporary solution where i can use arrays here to get it solve

let bookingArray = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Booking.self, from: data)
can you tell me what should i use before the above line?
i wrote below code:
let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
print("all data new==>>",jsonResponse)
and getting response as well.
but after that line
let bookingArray = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Booking.self, from: data)
getting empty

I've posted all code you need. data should be the JSON data response from your backend. Use do {  let bookingArray = try JSONDecoder().decode(Booking.self, from: data) } catch { print(error) } instead and check the decoding error. Make sure to use a custom JSONDecoder if you need a custom dateDecodingStrategy.

I tried it by using do-catch block and finally got the error due to which i was getting empty array. The error was "valueNotFound(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil)...." some values from the response can be nil.
After removing those values, I got the desired output.
Thanks a lot Leo. :)

Hey Leo,
can you once look at this question below?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78645988/tableview-not-showing-correct-data
