UITableview not showing correct data in UIKit
I am implementing a tableview(Lets say Main tableview) which has another tableview(call it inner tableview) in its cell. So in viewcontroller i am calling api and appending two nested arrays.
When i am using static data for the tableview its showing correct data but when i am using data from response its showing correct data only to first 3-4 cells after scrolling cells starts showing wrong and repeated data.
I have tried below code.
I have two arrays.
var memberArray = [[String]]() 
var memberTestsArray = [[[String]]]() 
var listArray: ListResponse?

In view controller i have,
i have function,
func getAllBookings() {
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "mylistUrl")!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
        urlRequest.headers = APINetworkClass.shared.getHeader()
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "Get"
//        print("urlRequest==>>",urlRequest)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else if let data = data ,let responseCode = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                do {
                    // Parse your response here.
                    let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
                    print("all data new==>>",jsonResponse)
                    do {
                        let bookingArray = try JSONDecoder().decode(BookingRevamp.self, from: data)
                        var results: [[[String]]] = []
                        for result in bookingArray.results {
                            let packages = result.packages.map(\.name)
                            let additionalMembers = result.additionalMembers.flatMap(\.packages).map(\.name)
                            if additionalMembers.isEmpty {
                                results.append([packages])
                            } else {
                                results.append([packages, additionalMembers])
                            }
                        }
                        self.membersTestsAndPackageArray = results
                     } catch {
                        print("inside catch one error==>>",error)
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("inside catch two error ",error)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.bookingListTableview.reloadData()
                }
             }
        }.resume()
    }

also mainTableview for which i have below code,
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return listArray?.results?.count ?? 0
    }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let bookingListRevampCell = self.bookingListTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookingListRevampTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? bookingListRevampTableViewCell
        bookingListRevampCell?.sectionArray = self.memberArray[indexPath.section]
        bookingListRevampCell?.memberTestPackageArray = self.membersTestsArray[indexPath.section] 
        return bookingListRevampCell ?? UITableViewCell()
}


And in my tableviewcell,
I have arrays , labels and tableview with header and footer,
   var sectionArray = [String]()
   var memberTestPackageArray = [[String]]()
   @IBOutlet weak var bookingViewMembersTableview: UITableView!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        bookingViewMembersTableview.delegate = self
        bookingViewMembersTableview.dataSource = self
        self.bookingViewMembersTableview.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options:            NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        idLabel.text = ""
        statusLabel.text = ""
        dateTimeLabel.text = ""
        amountLabel.text = ""
        viewBookingLabel.text = ""
    }


and innerTableviewMethods are as below,
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionArray.count
    }
    
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return memberTestPackageArray[section].count
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let bookingViewMemberCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "innerViewMembersTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! innerViewMembersTableViewCell
        bookingViewMemberCell.testPackageNameLabel.text = memberTestPackageArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return bookingViewMemberCell
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = .white
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: -15, width: tableView.frame.size.width - 30, height: 30))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1369999945, green: 0.3569999933, blue: 0.5569999814, alpha: 1)
        label.textColor = UIColor.hexString("#000000")
        label.text = sectionArray[section]
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        return headerView
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footView = UIView()
        footView.backgroundColor = .white
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width - 30, height: 30))
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1369999945, green: 0.3569999933, blue: 0.5569999814, alpha: 1)
        label.text = "Download"
        footView.addSubview(label)
    //add download button instead of label
        return footView
    }

The tableview is dynamic height tableview.
When i am scrolling updown the data is changing.
How can i fix this?

You should just do let bookingListRevampCell = self.bookingListTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookingListRevampTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! bookingListRevampTableViewCell - Your cell won't suddenly not be available and there is no point in returning an empty table view cell; Just crash and it will let you know you have a problem during development

You need to call bookingListRevampCell.bookingViewMembersTableview.reloadData() in your outer table cellForRowAt - or put self.bookingViewMembersTableview.reloadData() in a didSet on memberTestPackageArray

hey i have already done it and looks like it is working. :) bookingListRevampCell.bookingViewMembersTableview.reloadData()
But just another issue occured.
I just logged in with another account in my app that has large and nested data, in that case i got a crash at line, that is inside tableview cell.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return memberTestPackageArray[section].count
}
the error is Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
